# How to extract element with an ID that has text of two words length using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="646BED8B" w14:textId="30F19BEA" w:rsidR="00CA7979" w:rsidRDefault="00197F7D">
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">This </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00656E17">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">first sentence </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T16:15:00Z" w:id="0">
        <w:r w:rsidR="00E24CA3">
            <w:t>is</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T16:15:00Z" w:id="1">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="00E24CA3" w:rsidR="00656E17">
            <w:delText>was</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">for checking the verb usage errors.  I will</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T16:18:00Z" w:id="2">
        <w:r w:rsidR="00BF77BA">
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">write</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T16:18:00Z" w:id="3">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="00BF77BA">
            <w:delText xml:space="preserve">make</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">some </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00BF77BA">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>changes</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">to the verbs and check it if the verbs </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T16:15:00Z" w:id="4">
        <w:r w:rsidR="00E24CA3">
            <w:t>are</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T16:15:00Z" w:id="5">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="00E24CA3">
            <w:delText>is</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">fixed.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I have an array of verbs:

```
@verbs = ["is", "will", "write", "are", "should", "be", "will", "add", "see", "adding", "is", "should", "be", "inserted", "will", "delete", "view", "deleting", "works", "should", "be", "deleted", "tests", "adding", "should", "be", "was", "will", "make", "is", "should", "be", "will", "adding", "should", "be", "inserted", "will", "delete", "remove", "see", "deleting", "works", "working", "should", "be", "deleted", "test", "adding", "should", "be"]
```

I can get all of the elements with an w:id as follows:

```
@elements = @file.xpath('//*[@w:id]')
```

However, what I want to do is get only the elements in the file that match the following:

1. The text is 2 words or less
2. One of the words is included in my @verbs array.

Can I do this with Nokogiri and if so how?

Comment: Please reduce the size of your example XML. We need the absolute minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem with your code. Anything beyond that wastes space and our time. "[ask]", along with the linked pages, and "[mcve]" will help you. Also, “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)” is an important read. We'd like to see an example of the code you wrote that demonstrates the problem, not just a single line that doesn't approach solving it, and then some requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to mix in a bit of Ruby as well:

```
@file.xpath('//*[@w:id]').select { |node|
  words = node.text.split
  words.length <= 2 && words.any? { |word| @verbs.include?(word) }
}
```

---

It just occurred to me, if you have more than a few words to check, you'd be much happier by converting `@verbs` to a set:

```
require 'set'
@verbset = Set.new(@verbs)
```

and then checking `@verbset.include?(word)`, as it is much faster than testing for membership in an array.

Comment: Just tried it and it works perfectly! Awesome. Thanks for letting me know about mixing in Ruby, I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: Thanks again Amadan. I didn't know about set. Wish I could double vote you.

Comment: I tried it and am getting undefined method `include' for #<Set: {"am", "testing", "will", "use", "test"}> (NoMethodError). My bad I forgot the ?

Comment: Just noticed (and fixed) my typo: it's `include?`, not `include` (as is normal with Ruby's yes-or-no methods) - in fact, the same name as with an array. The only thing that was supposed to change is `@verbs` -> `@verbset`, but I messed up :P